# Run PHP CLI in Sublime Text 3 Console

Tags: php

I want to run php cli in sublime text 3 console. When i type `php -v` in sublime text console, it display

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'php' is not defined
```

Any help on above error?